# How can I get transaction event(commit, rollback)

Tags: events, transactions, ejb

I created a CMT based EJB. The EJB inserts a record into the database and then it executes another code(A) asynchronously. The ejb continues it's processing so the transaction can be committed or rolledback after asynchronous call.
In the code (A) I need to wait until the EJB's transaction committed or rolled back. Then read the record which the EJB inserted or skip next execution.
My question is that can I notified the EJB's transaction event or have to poll until I can read the record.

I'm working on the IBM WebSphere 7.0 (Java EE 5)

Comment: If there is dependency & have to wait until the record is inserted, then why the next method is called aynchronously instead of sequentially.

Comment: @NayanWadekar  Because the code that runs asynchronously might be very expensive and the calling business logic needs to proceed without caring about the other stuff that happens (e.g. writing statistics, reporting something, sending emails etc.). Would be stupid if your web page does not load because the EJB code waits for the email server to send a registration confirmation, wouldn't it

Comment: @bennidi `I need to wait until the EJB's transaction committed or rolled back`. So it would not be **stupid** if web page loads & fail to send confirmation, how does the end-user gets notified, revisit after sometime, if doesn't need to wait. People here aren't paid/hired, but because of interest & not bound to give clarifications. Refrain from posting totally irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to synchronize asynchronously invoked code with transaction events, as far as I know, is to use CDI events. In the code that runs inside the transaction you have to send a CDI event. You can configure the handler of the CDI event to run only on certain transaction outcomes - these handlers are called transactional observers.

I found this page from the JBoss docs that outline the syntax and general concept - see section 11.7

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/events.html

Basically it looks like this

```
public void refreshCategoryTree(@Observes(during = AFTER_SUCCESS) CategoryUpdateEvent event) 
{// only called after the transaction committed successfully }
```

I don't know about WebSphere but since this is part of the CDI Spec I would assume it should work there as well. I once used this with JBoss and it worked for me. You can even have the handler run inside its own transaction if you want.

Comment: Unfortunatly he uses version 5 of JavaEE, so CDI won't be included as it is only from version 6 of JavaEE (and in version 1.0 moreover) right ?

Comment: And CDI events does not works correclty with Websphere 8.5+ (and so CDI 1.0) Transactional observers must be @Singleton and not CDI beans, Observation methods must be defined into a business interfaces, transactional observation fails if you have multiple observers for the same event kind, etc. Forget this option with Websphere unless you have time to open PMR / wait for fixes.